# Store Documents (.pdf, .doc etc..) related to a web application

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a web applications Php and Mysql where I need to store large number of documents(word docs,pdfs,images etc...) and the path to reach each document is in the Mysql database. These documents (contracts signed, privacy acceptance signed etc..) would be uploaded mainly by the users, that are all linked with company (employees and agents). Thus could all use a VPN and User and Password to enter in the system.
The question is, in terms of architecture, where I can store this document? And how can I be sure none not authorized access to this server folder?

I have asked to hosting providers and they do not allow to store documents on their web server.

Comment: The primary function of a web server is to return stored documents, so their claim that they do not allow such is complete nonsense.  Rather than "VPN", have you considered building a web front-end through which users will authenticate and interact with the storage system?

Comment: Reply of Hosting provider surprised me as well. Of course users has to autenticate, I will hide the DB connection script. By the way my question was a bit more on the architecture, where I should have documents file, on the server? on an FTP server? Use an HTTPS rather than HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to block un-authorized access ,

1. Generate a random file name , and upload a htaccess file to block directory listing
2. you should save them outside of root folder (secure)

Comment: Directory listing is one of my main concern, but I'm not sure I got your suggest on how to block it. what do you mean with HTaccess file to block directory listing?

Comment: Add this ` Options -Indexes` for more info www.thesitewizard.com/apache/prevent-directory-listing-htaccess.shtml